# run php script on arduino (as a web server)

Tags: php, server, arduino

I'm on project where the Arduino act as a web server.

I need to run PHP code inside using the arduino.

Is there any way to run PHP using arduino ?

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't the place for those questions.

Comment: No. It is not possible to run any scripting language on an Arduino.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as  **stevieb** says:

> No. It is not possible to run any scripting language on an Arduino

so i've found anther way to do this, i've upload my PHP script to host and then called it in arduino using html **iframe** .

that is the only way.

Comment: Can you explain how you did that ?

Answer (score 0):

https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/WebClient

Arduino docs give an example of how to do this.

Comment: this is HTTP not PHP

Comment: Yes but the process is the same. There are lots of docs on this on Stack Overflow.

Comment: there are no docs anywhere about running php on avr because that doesn't exist.